# Python fetch attribute_id from attribute_name from Json when having many attribute ids

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a method in order to fetch an attribute value from a JSON. I have the workspaceName: "example2" and I need to fetch the value of the workspaceID for that workspaceName (002). It may seem easy but I haven't been able to accomplish it. Could you help me? This is the JSON

```
[
   {
       "workspaceName": "example1",
       "workspaceID": "001"
   },
   {
       "workspaceName": "example2", <--- From this workspaceName
       "workspaceID": "002" . <--- Get this id 002
   },
       {
       "workspaceName": "example3",
       "workspaceID": "003"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below method in order to get id.

```
    list1 = [
       {
       "workspaceName": "example1",
       "workspaceID": "001"
       },
       {
       "workspaceName": "example2", <--- From this workspaceName
       "workspaceID": "002" . <--- Get this id 002
       },
       {
       "workspaceName": "example3",
       "workspaceID": "003"
       }
    ]

    value = 'example2'
    for data in list1:
        if value in data.values():
            index = list1.index(data)
            print list1[index]['workspaceID']
```